# Php for loop array not working

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I'll Post, HELLO, WORLD

Expecting

```
HELLO,6
H
E
L
L
O
,
WORLD5
W
O
R
L
D
```

Instead I get

```
HELLO,6
H
E
L
L
O
,

WORLD5
```

There 2nd word will not spell?

```
$name = $_POST['engname'];
$convert = array_combine($letters, $jap);

function get_num_of_names($name) {
    $name = explode(" ",  $name);
        $name_mainlen = count($name);


        for($i=0; $i <= $name_mainlen + 1; $i++) {
            echo $name[$i];
            $name[$i] = str_split($name[$i]);
            $namelen = count($name[$i]);
            echo $namelen . '<br/>';

            function spellname($x, $namelen) {
                for($i=0; $i <= $namelen; $i++) {
                    echo $x[$i] . '<br/>';
                }   
            }
            spellname($name[$i], $namelen);
        }


}
get_num_of_names($name);
```

Comment: add this to the bottom your script.. check your variables & arrays...

print_r(get_defined_vars());

post your output...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're defining a function in a loop. Your script should implode with a `Function 'spellname' already defined` error, if you'd activate error reporting.

A function is defined when it is encountered. If you place it in a loop, it will be defined on each iteration. Since you can't define two functions with the same name, your script aborts with a fatal error.

Apart from that, there are much easier ways to do what you want to do:

```
$str = 'Hello World';
$words = explode(' ', $str);
$output = array();
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $output[] = join('<br />', str_split($word));
}
echo join('<br /><br />', $output);
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
echo join('<br /><br />', array_map(create_function('$a', 'return join("<br />", str_split($a));'), explode(' ', $str)));
```

Or, even shorter with different approach (regards to @Long Ears):

```
echo join('<br />', str_replace(' ', '', str_split($str)));
```

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that my revised code doesn't adhere 100% to the "spec", as it doesn't print the entire word and its length before breaking it down, and it's also not using commas. I'll leave that as an exercise to the OP. :)

Comment: A much simpler but equivalent one-liner: `echo join('<br />', str_replace(' ', '', str_split($str)));`

Comment: And slightly less horrid than create_function(), how about a regex using a conditional sub-pattern and a non-matching assertion to capture a string which doesn't exist in the subject ;) `echo preg_replace('#(?(?= )(?!(<br />))|).#', '$0<br />$2', $str);`

Comment: The reason why I did it the way I was doing it, is so I can use the letters as an arrays key and replace it with the arrays value.

Comment: @Long `create_function` ain't pretty, but it works and is more comprehensible than that regex. ;-) I have to admit your `str_replace` approach is clever, but you won't be able to get the same results as the OP. Neither does my code right now, but it's extensible.

Comment: @Matthew Not sure why you'd want to use the letters as array keys. That means you can have only one `L` per array...

Comment: Fair point on the extensibility, I'm just a sucker for one-liners :) Having said that I wouldn't wish `create_function` on anyone. It's a shame 5.3 isn't ubiquitous enough yet to use closures everywhere ;)

Comment: @Long Agreed. I'm only staying 5.2 compatible because 5.3 just isn't there yet. `create_function` is perfectly fine for short expressions such as this.

Comment: @deceze I'm breaking up the words to there characters and using those characters to give me the value so I can convert the characters into fake Japanese characters, basically as a super simple joke translation tool. Who knew something like that could be so hard, I swear twitter is easier to make.

Answer (score 4):

You're defining the same function twice which should result in a noticable error, so ensure that error_reporting is E_ALL and display_errors is on in your php.ini.

In this case however you don't need the function, you can just loop `$name` instead of `$x`.

Comment: I finnally turned display_errors on, and wow so many errors, but it's sort of fun to debug and watch each error disappear! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**dude, there is a function in your for loop!!! wtf???**

would be the reply I would give if one of my friends would come to me with this code(that would be an unlikely scenerio though). basicly you shouldn't do that.

Comment: I was going to downvote you for douche-factor, then I read the second paragraph and wanted to upvote you for the laugh.  Net 0 votes (really because Deceze answer hit it spot-on) but I appreciated your response.

Answer (score 1):

Further to other comments your function is called get_num_of_names, but would be better called print_names_and_their_letters as getting the number of names is only a tiny part of the function.

Comment: Thank you for refreshing my memory on how to name function names.